# VIsVim search light color on dark scheme

Tags: visual-studio, vim, color-scheme

I am very happy to use VisVim plugin but there is one very annoying thing.
When I am searching for something i get this annoying light selection color. I don`t know how to change it. I have tried every color setting in **Tools/Options/Environment/Fonts and Colors**
 and I have not found it.

Can you please help me because i don`t want to remove VisVim because of that.

[image: colors messed up]

Thanks.

Comment: In real Vim, you'd do `:set nohlsearch` to disable it completely (well, it's off by default) or `:noh` to turn it off until next search. See if something like that works.

Comment: But I want to have hl, only different color :)

Comment: I'm not sure if it's relevant but have you checked the default Visual Studio colour settings under Tools->Options->Environment->Fonts and Colors? See if changing the values for Selected Text and Inactive Selected Text makes any difference.

Comment: Found the answer on a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25007059/highlighting-makes-code-unreadable-when-searching-with-vsvim

Answer (score 2):

You can change these settings using Visual studio options,
Change "VsVim Highlight Incremental Search" settings in 
"Tools->Options->Environment->Fonts and Colors".
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about VisVim, but in Vim the search highlighting is governed by the `Search` highlight group. You can set this globally in your .vimrc by specifying the desired foreground and background colours:

```
hi Search guifg=black guibg=yellow
```

But note that this will be overridden if you change the colourscheme after starting Vim. A better way would be to modify the colourscheme file itself. You can find the name of the current scheme by typing `:colo`, which should be somewhere in your `.vim` directory (usually in `.vim\colors`, depending on your system). You just need to modify the `hi Search` line in this file.

Apologies if this is not relevant to VisVim.

Comment: I have tried that. My Vim settings are ok. The trick is in VisVim and Visual studio integration. But thanks anyway.