# Highlighting makes code unreadable when searching with VsVim

Tags: visual-studio-2012, vsvim

I've been using VsVim for a while and I have been pretty happy with it. However, the one thing that has been annoying me is the highlighting of text when I do any kind of search in VsVim such using `*` or the standard search with `/`.

I've spent hours trying to change the fonts and colors in the Visual Studios options menu, but I haven't found a way to change the color scheme. Below is a picture with the highlight text. Any help on this matter would greatly improve my productivity.

[image: search highlight making code unreadable]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately there is a bug in the handling of fonts / colors in Visual Studio that makes it impossible to change the highlight color in VsVim through the standard Fonts and Colors options page.  The most recent version of VsVim (1.7.0) added a custom color menu to its option page which allows for this, and a few other, colors to be changed

Just go to Tools -> Options -> VsVim

[image]

Comment: The new version's color options page was able to fix my problem. Thank you. Also, thank you for maintaining VsVim, it makes using Visual Studio so much easier.

Comment: I also had to run `:set hlsearch` to get the search results to actually highlight.